# How to monkey patch __init__ module in Python?

Tags: python, django, init, monkeypatching

I know, I know, it's dirty and all. I want to know if it's possible to hijack the `__init__` module of a Python module to replace it by your own.

I'm asking that because I need to prevent a django lib to start some part of it's init process that make it crashes with our configuration.

And yes, it's better to fix the django lib and send back a patch. Yes, I'm in touch with the author about that. But for now, I need a quick fix.

Comment: How about just editing the `__init__.py` to your liking? It's all just plain text

Answer (score 4):

One way to hijack the import procedure is to simulate the import sometime before it takes place, in another module that is imported before the one you want to monkey-patch. Insert whatever you want into `sys.modules` with the name of the module as the key, and when the time comes to import the original module, Python will find an entry in `sys.modules` and will just use that. This may not work if the import is done in some magic way.

On the other hand, you can always just copy the original project and patch it to your liking.

Comment: +1 but I failed doing that. I can't see how to replace it properly. If I set the entry in the module dict, then I can't import the ohter submodules because my version is not in the same directory.

Comment: Right, I figured you might have problems with importing submodules. In you could try and import those submodules manually too, but I'm not sure of the best way to do that. One last thing you may try is temporarily monkey-patching any outside functions/globals/etc. that the module in question uses. After all, if the module is doing something involving side-effects, it is probably calling some outside functions or modifying globals. Do the patching just before the import and reset the monkey-patches right after, and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit the `__init__.py` file. There's nothing stopping you and if you do it right nothing bad will happen.

Comment: I was about to comment that should be an answer. +1

Comment: -1. I know I can do it. And I did. I made a patch and shared it with my colleague. But the question is not 'can you solve my problem with this app?'. My question is: can you hijack __init__ ?

Comment: hack something simply because you can and one day end up with broken unmaintanable code